setup hedera local network
I'm trying to run a Hedera local node locally, and I'm following the docker set up instructions followed by these instructions to set up a localhost network, but then hoping to change the connection settings to be able to connect to Hedera Testnet, instead of my own private network. But I got this error:
Error: MaxAttemptsOrTimeoutError: max attempts of 10 was reached for request with last error being: GrpcServiceError: gRPC service failed with: Status: TIMEOUT, Code: 17
    at AccountCreateTransaction.execute (C:\Users\souha\OneDrive\Desktop\Souhail\Hedera\hello-hedera-js-sdk\node_modules\@hashgraph\sdk\lib\Executable.cjs:677:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
    at async main (C:\Users\souha\OneDrive\Desktop\Souhail\Hedera\hello-hedera-js-sdk\index.js:25:22) {
  nodeAccountId: '0.0.3'
}

Here is the code I am running:
const {
  Client,
  PrivateKey,
  AccountId,
  AccountCreateTransaction,
  Hbar,
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");

async function main() {
  // Operator credentials
  const operatorAccountId = "0.0.5163020"; // Default operator account
  const operatorPrivateKey = PrivateKey.fromString(
    "302e020100300506032b657004220420200c4b94c8449cb9b024fd9048c863245e5397d408771c7d86b58cb1ac602856" // Replace with private key from logs
  );

  // Node configuration
  const node = { "127.0.0.1:50211": new AccountId(3) }; // Node account ID is often `0.0.3`
  const client = Client.forNetwork(node).setMirrorNetwork("127.0.0.1:5600");

  // Set the operator
  client.setOperator(operatorAccountId, operatorPrivateKey);

  // Create a new account
  const newKey = PrivateKey.generateED25519();
  const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction()
    .setKey(newKey.publicKey)
    .setInitialBalance(Hbar.fromTinybars(1000))
    .execute(client);

  const receipt = await newAccount.getReceipt(client);
  console.log("New Account ID:", receipt.accountId);
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error:", err);
});

